# How to delete a common row from multiple tables using SQL

Tags: sql

I understand you can delete from multiple tables using joins. But, I'm not sure how to do that. I tried using this statement and it didn't work either.

```
delete trm, val 
from MCS.stg_mdcr_trmntn_rpt trm, MCS.stg_mdcr_vldtn_rpt val
where trm.import_proc_id = 156;
```

Comment: on what column do you want to join?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL supports a multi table delete but SQL Server doesn't for example.

Comment: you can't delete fields like that... cause I suppose trm and val are fields right ?

Comment: It almost looks like its not a field, but rather an alias...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
delete from MCS.stg_mdcr_trmntn_rpt 
where import_proc_id = 156;

delete from MCS.stg_mdcr_vldtn_rpt
where import_proc_id = 156;

commit;
```